# php pdo code to insert row dynamically from user input

Tags: php, pdo

my question is--

column name -   total

textbox name - totalloop

I need is when user **enter 5 in totalloop textbox..then 5 rows inserted** in DB.

And Value goes inside  **total column** is like **1,2,3,4,5**    .........ok.

Again when  when user **enter 3 in totalloop textbox..then 3 rows inserted** in DB.

And Value goes inside  **total column** is from **6,7,8**   .........ok.

every think is working fine from my code ....

plz suggest where to place my query and variable to to insert max value every time from loops inside database column.

```
   if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {       
                    $book_no = $_POST['book_no'];                   
                    $created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");                     

                    $query = $database->getRow("SELECT MAX(book_no) AS max1 FROM scheme_master;");
                        $largestNumber = $query['max1'];
                        $top = $largestNumber + 1;  

                    for($row=1;$row<=$book_no;$row++)
                    {   

                        $insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO scheme_master (book_no,created) VALUES (:book_no,:created)", 
                        array(':book_no'=>$top,':created'=>$created));
                    }
                    $_SESSION['message'] = "Books Created Successfully";                        
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I think auto-increment is something wonderfull for you?!

Comment: are you asking for the html form code?

Comment: thank sir for your response..........i got succesful  result in my code . i have done this. thanks....

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {       
                    $book_no = $_POST['book_no'];                   
                    $created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");                         
                    for($row=1;$row<=$book_no;$row++)
                    {   
                        $query = $database->getRow("SELECT MAX(book_no) AS max1 FROM scheme_master;");
                        $largestNumber = $query['max1'];
                        $top = $largestNumber + 1;
                        $insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO scheme_master (book_no,created) VALUES (:book_no,:created)", 
                        array(':book_no'=>$top,':created'=>$created));
                    }
                    $_SESSION['message'] = "Books Created Successfully";                        
    }
```

this code gets input from user ...loop insert query according to the inputed value ...and every time insert max + 1 value in DB column.